# Why this while-case does not work in Ubuntu?

Tags: shell-script, getopts

I am switching away from BSD to completely Linux.
Script in Ubuntu 16.04

```
#!/bin/sh
while (( "$#" )); do
   case "$1" in
    -i | --ignore-case)
        [ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "2 arguments i needed" && exit 1
        case_option=-i
        ;;
    -*)
        echo "Error: Unknown option: $1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
     *) # No more options
        break
        ;;
   esac

   shift
done

# -o, if not, then ...
find $HOME ! -readable -prune -o \
    -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l $case_option "$1" {} + | vim -R -
```

Mistake is in looping.

- `sh ./script masi` returns the same output as the expected output.
- Run `sh ./script -i masi`. Output: blank file. Expected output: list of results. STOUT is `./script: 2: ./script: 2: not found Vim: Reading from stdin...`.

Possible mistakes

- `while (( "$#" ))`
- ...

I cannot use the options at all for some reason.

### Moving to getopts - motivation by terdon's answer

[Tutorial](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14458401/54964)

```
case_option=""

while getopts "i:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        i | ignore_case) 
            [[ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "2 arguments i needed" && exit 1
            case_option=-i
            ;;
        -*)
            echo "Error: Unknown option: $1" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        *) # No more options 
           break
           ;;
    esac
done

find $HOME ! -readable -prune -o \
   -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -l $case_option "$1" {} + | vim -R -
```

where

- calling by `./script masi` or `./script -i masi`.

---

How can you do cases in `while` loop?

Comment: "preferably non-GNU"? Then why bash and ubuntu?

Comment: So ... what happens? Why can't you use the options at all?

Comment: `getopts` (the shell built-in) doesn't support `--long` options, only short options.  If you want long options, you'll have to either write your own option processing code or use `getopt` (without the `s` on the end) from the `util-linux` package.  **DO NOT** use any other version of `getopt`, they are all broken and unsafe to use, `util-linux`'s `getopt` is the only one that works.  I use the built-in `getopts` only whenever I need portability, and `getopt` for everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two examples of options processing, first with the shell built-in `getopts` and then with `getopt` from `util-linux`.

`getopts` doesn't support `--long` options, only short options.

`getopt` supports both.  If you want to use `getopt`, use ONLY the version from the `util-linux` package. **DO NOT** use any other version of getopt, they are all broken and unsafe to use, `util-linux`'s `getopt` is the only one that works.

Fortunately, on Linux, the `util-linux` version is the only version you're likely to have unless you go out of your way to install a broken version.

`getopts` is more portable (works in most or all bourne-shell descendants) and does more for you automatically (e.g. less setup is required and you don't need to run `shift` or `shift 2` for every option, depending on whether the option takes an argument or not) but is less capable (it doesn't support long options).

Anyway, in addition to processing the `-i` (`--ignore-case`) option, I've added a `-h` (`--help`) option and an example of an option that requires an argument `-x` (`--example`).  It does nothing useful, it's just there to show you how to do it.

With `getopts`, the code is:

```
#! /bin/bash

usage() {
# a function that prints an optional error message and some help.
# and then exits with exit code 1
[ -n "$*" ] && printf "%s\n" "$*" > /dev/stderr

cat <<__EOF__
Usage:
      $0 [-h] [ -i ] [ -x example_data ]

-i    Ignore case
-x    The example option, requires an argument.
-h     This help message.

Detailed help message here
__EOF__

exit 1
}

case_option=''
case_example=''

while getopts "hix:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h) usage ;;
        i) case_option='-i' ;;
        x) case_example="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) usage ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

find "$HOME" ! -readable -prune -o -type f -name "*.tex" \
    -exec grep -l ${case_option:+"$case_option"} "$1" {} + |
    vim -R -
```

With `getopt` from `util-linux`:

```
#! /bin/bash

usage() {
# a function that prints an optional error message and some help.
# and then exits with exit code 1
[ -n "$*" ] && printf "%s\n" "$*" > /dev/stderr

cat <<__EOF__
Usage:
      $0 [ -h ] [ -i ] [ -x example_data ]
      $0 [ --help ] [ --ignore-case ] [ --example example_data ]

-i, --ignore-case    Ignore case
-x, --example        The example option, requires an argument.
-h, --help           This help message

Detailed help message here
__EOF__

exit 1
}

case_option=''
case_example=''

# getopt is only safe if GETOPT_COMPATIBLE is not set.
unset GETOPT_COMPATIBLE

# POSIXLY_CORRECT disables getopt parameter shuffling, so nuke it.
# parameter shuffling moves all non-option args to the end, after
# all the option args.  e.g. args like "-x -y file1 file2 file3 -o optval"
# become "-x -y -o optval -- file1 file2 file3"
unset POSIXLY_CORRECT

OPTS_SHORT='hix:'
OPTS_LONG='help,ignore-case,example:'
# check options and shuffle them
TEMP=$(getopt -o "$OPTS_SHORT" --long "$OPTS_LONG" -n "$0" -- "$@")

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then usage ; fi

# assign the re-ordered options & args to this shell instance
eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
  case "$1" in
    -i|--ign*) case_option='-i' ; shift ;;
    -x|--exa*) case_example="$2" ; shift 2 ;;

    -h|--hel*) usage ;;

    --) shift ; break ;;
     *) usage ;;
  esac
done

find "$HOME" ! -readable -prune -o -type f -name "*.tex" \
    -exec grep -l ${case_option:+"$case_option"} "$1" {} + |
    vim -R -
```

Comment: Never use `getopt`, it is outdated since 30 years. BTW: whether `getopts` supports long options depends on the shell.

Comment: @Masi, I use both. Mostly, I use getopt because i like the long option capability.  I use getopts when portability is required.  Ignore schily, he knows nothing about the util-linux version of `getopt` (he's also prejudiced against anything involving linux or GNU).  BTW, both versions above work...what do you mean by "blank outputs..."

Comment: This is a great answer! Your code works as expected. It is easily the best here with clearest explanation and how the things should be done.

Comment: Where's the "+perm" and "0666" coming from?  What changes did you make - neither of the examples above use `-perm` or anything similar.  BTW, the examples above were about getopt/getopts and the while loop and case statement as in your original question, not about `find`.  .  If you have specific questions about `find`, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

It is failing because you are running it using `dash` and not `sh` or `bash`. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`, a minimal, POSIX compliant shell. The simplest solution is to run your script with `bash` instead where it will work as expected:

```
bash ./script masi
```

Also, note that you have a shebang line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Which means you don't need to run `sh ./script`, you can simply do `./script`. Just change the shebang line to point to bash instead of `sh`:

```
#/bin/bash
```

---

If you insist on using `sh` (`dash` on Ubuntu), you need to change the `while` loop to:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
```

Alternatively, you might want to look into [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html).

Comment: @Masi it's just a more elegant way of getting command line switches than manually writing case statements for all of them. See here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: @Masi have a look at the tutorial I linked to above. Yours is a very simple case and covered there.

Answer (score 1):

`getopts` handles option arguments, what your script does will not work.

Here is a working small framework:

```
case_option="" 

while getopts "i:" opt; do 
    case $opt in 
        'i') 
                I_ARG=$OPTARG 
                ;; 
        '?') 
                exit 1 
                ;;  
    esac 
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1)) 
echo $@
```

Comment: Using what input? Note that you may like to add `echo $I_ARG` to check the -i argument.

Comment: Your find command does not really make sense. You defined a script that implements an option `-i` that takes an argument, but the find command line does not fit to that concept.

Comment: as mentioned, this does not make sense as your script was wrong and as you do not explain what you like to have as additional grep option.

Comment: You still did not explain how you like to get this "masi" from the command line ad this seems to be you main problem.